# Deleting emails in the online GMail list, does not delete them on my Android 2.2 Samsung Galaxy S, is this normal?

Tags: gmail

This morning I decided to **clean up my emails** list in my gmail account using the Windows wb browser.

However when I **opened the gmail application on my Samsung Galaxy S** running Froyo 2.2, the **emails I deleted online where still present**.

Is this normal behavior or is there a setting which controls this.

I looked around for some setting, but found none. I also looked at the help on Gmail where is explained that you can clear the gmail's application data, but was just wondering whether there wasn't an easier way. All in all, this seems to be a logical operation no?

Comment: How soon after you deleted them on the web did you look in the GMail app? Do you have background sync turned on on your phone, and does your phone have a data connection at the moment?

Comment: @GATHrawn: Yes to all questions: I have background sync on, I had a data connection, and a mail just received in gmail for the web, was also there in the gmail for the android. anyway, regardless whether background syncing is on, if I press 'refresh', the data should be synced write than and there , no ? I just checked again, and the deleted items are still there on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha I have found it : the emails were still in the trash. Once I viewed the trash, highlighted them all, and than choose the 'Delete permanently', than when syncing on the device, the 'deleted' mails were gone too.

GAThrawn was so convincing in his reply that they should have been deleted, I investigated some more ... thanks.

*I will keep my answer here, since it might help others in the future.*

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether they're in the Trash, or not. I've never emptied the trash folder in Gmail, just let it auto-empty. At the moment I've got over 250 messages in trash. Pretty sure that GMail sets priorities on what it syncs and how often, so new emails are synced almost instantly, whereas I've seen deletions take up to 15 minutes (hence my question about how soon you looked). I just tested with a message I reported as spam on the web, and it was just over five minutes before it disappeared from my phone even pressing refresh.

Comment: Wait, people actually delete emails from GMail besides spam? :)  Yes, I agree with GAThrawn, it can take a couple minutes for gmail app to sync up with gmail.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't matter, but I can only tell (and ask) about things I notice on my phone. I will do some further testing ...